# because the test, phpunit and laravel give a successful answer, but it should be the opposite.?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I currently have a controller, with its path declared like this:

```
Route::resource('/route_testing', 'RouteTestingController')->middleware('checkPermission:my_permission_index');
```

he accesses the store() method

and I have my test done like this:

```
public function testCreateExcessCarriers(){
        $formData = [
            'user_id' => 1233,
            'agency_id' => 444,
            'uuid' => \Uuid::generate(),
            'email' => 'faker@faker.com',
            'name' => 'faker name'
        ];
        //$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $this->post(route('route_testing.store'), $formData)
             ->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

The problem I have is that in my controller the store () method is commented, I have commented to see if the error in the test jumps.

That the `store()` method in the controller is commented, that is to say as it would not exist but in the test if it gives OK, I understand it is because if you made the insert which I understand it cannot be true since it is commented. And if I try it from the front, it effectively jumps Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error. Shouldn't it be the same in the test?

[image]

Comment: What is the error

Comment: That the `store()` method in the controller is commented, that is to say as it would not exist but in the test if it gives OK, I understand it is because if you made the insert which I understand it cannot be true since it is commented. And if I try it from the front, it effectively jumps Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error. Shouldn't it be the same in the test?

Comment: it must be the middleware redirect to another valid url.